# Performance Issue after Truncate and Load of a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, truncate

One of our clients has migrated from old to new (larger size/resources) servers. A process (X) is taking 4 hours extra whenever we are doing a truncate and full load of a specific table. If we do not truncate-load this table X doesn't take long to run. In process X we are inserting, updating and reading data from this table into numerous temp tables and then using these temp tables further.

I would like to know:

- Best practices whenever a truncate and full load is performed.
- What steps can we take from our side on this specific table?
- Does the database migration to another server bring such issues?
- What debugging should I do? I am gathering stats with cascade after the full load on this table, then running the process X.
- Is it recommended to update any Oracle parameters on moving from Oracle 12c from Oracle 11g or 10?

Sorry for being very generic. The exact usage of the table in process X is complex and difficult to mention here. Please advise.

Other details:
Table Structure is as follows: - Around 55 columns -PCT_FREE    10 PCT_USED INI_TRANS   1 MAX_TRANS 255 INITIAL_EXTENT  65536 NEXT_EXTENT   1048576 MIN_EXTENTS 1 MAX_EXTENTS   2147483645 PCT_INCREASE FREELISTS   FREELIST_GROUPS LOGGING YES BACKED_UP   N NUM_ROWS 4064125

Typical weekly full load inserts around 2-3Million records

I am doing gather stats to the table and other related tables as well, with following options: dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=>'schema_x', tabname => 'Table', estimate_percent => dbms_stats.auto_sample_size, method_opt => 'for all columns size auto', cascade=>TRUE, DEGREE=>7)
Table has two Normal Unique index and one Normal Non-Unique index defined

Comment: More information about the tables in question and the data itself will help (such as size and how much changes each time)

Comment: Typical weekly full load inserts around 2-3Million records.

Comment: Please include that information in the question as it matters if the records have a few columns versus a hundred. Also if there are constraints on the table in question that will matter as well

Comment: Table Structure is as follows:
- Around 55 columns
-PCT_FREE 10
PCT_USED 
INI_TRANS 1
MAX_TRANS 255
INITIAL_EXTENT 65536
NEXT_EXTENT 1048576
MIN_EXTENTS 1
MAX_EXTENTS 2147483645
PCT_INCREASE 
FREELISTS 
FREELIST_GROUPS 
LOGGING YES
BACKED_UP N
NUM_ROWS 4064125

Comment: Table has two Normal Unique index and one Normal Non-Unique index defined
UNIQUE INDEX ."SA_STK" ON "table" ("ID1", "ID2", "RecTYPE", "RecON", "RecBACK", "RecNEW", "RecBad", "ONHANDFIXED")

Comment: Did you `GATHER_TABLE_STATS` after loading new data into the table?

Comment: Yes, I did gather stats to the table and other related tables as well, with following options:
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=>'schema_x',
  tabname          => 'Table',
  estimate_percent => dbms_stats.auto_sample_size,
  method_opt       => 'for all columns size auto',
  cascade=>TRUE, 
  DEGREE=>7)

Comment: Please edit this information into the question as it makes it much harder for people to help you if they have to get information from the comments.

Comment: How are you loading your table?  Via a select from other table(s)?  DataPump import?  Is the database in archivelog mode?  I know some solutions once you provide this information.

Comment: The data loading process is as follows:
- ETL Load data from file to staging table
- Core Process loads data from this staging table with some calculations.
-Process X updates, inserts and reads data from table in its processing.

I'll check with the DBA for the archivelog mode and update in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

### Loading Truncated Table

Assume staging table is `X_SOURCE`, and target table to load is `X_TARGET`, and any calculations performed when loading `X_TARGET` can be done via SQL functions or user-defined functions.  Here we load `col_a` as is, inserting current date into `col_b`, `col_c` is multiplied by 2 times, and `col_d` as is.

```
alter table x_target nologging;
alter session enable parallel dml;
-- possibly drop indexes

insert /*+ append parallel(6) */ into X_TARGET 
   (select col_a, sysdate, col_c * 2, col_d from X_SOURCE);
-- recreate indexes if they were dropped
alter table x_target logging;

-- then invoke RMAN commands to back up the table
```

The above has the following features:

1. Turn off logging on the target table `x_target` to avoid logging
   overhead
2. The `/*+ append */` hint appends data to the end of the table
   and bypasses several steps done during normal inserts
3. Dropping and recreating the indexes can be much quicker than doing index
   maintenance during the load.
4. Don't forget to turn logging back on
5. Ensure a backup is done after the load

### New Server Issues

If the new server has more CPU/memory/etc. and you are seeing longer run time, I would definitely run the `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SYSTEM_STATS('START', ...)` procedure, (after creating a table to store the stats being gathered), run your truncate/load process, then run `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SYSTEM_STATS('STOP')`  and then query your stats table, and use `DBMS_STATS.SET_SYSTEM_STATS` to set values that need to be adusted -- see Performance Tuning Guide for details.  If you are on Oracle 12, also look at `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_PROCESSING_RATE` -- run it too while your process is running.